# Vertically align middle issue

Tags: html, css

here a parent div like this

```
.div parent{
width:100%;
height:100%;
text-align:center;
}
.div child{
width:10%;
height:10%;
}
```

In responsive web mobile devices the child div is not align vertically middle how can i align middle?? please help me..

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a JS fiddle of your problem?

Comment: Vertical alignment is difficult with divs. If you can get away with it, could you put it in a table? vertical alignment is easy with a table.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding :

```
.div parent{
vertical-align: middle;
width:100%;
height:100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written `.div parent` seems to be an **invalid selector**, If you are trying to select a `div` with class `parent`, it should be selected using `div.parent` (**Same applicable to your child div also**).

Try this;

Apply `diplay:table-cell;` to `.parent` div, So that it will get the ability to align its child vertically middle.

then apply `vertical-align:middle` to the same to make the child elements vertically middle

```
div.parent{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4AZY/2/)

This is an alternative take, using CSS tables

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>
            <div>Child</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
.cell div {
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but here is another approach with `Flex` (also available in CodePen - http://codepen.io/KErez/pen/kXzYAj):

HTML:

```
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>
    Inner
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (the colors are just for showing the boxes clearly):

```
.a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #223344;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.b {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #999999;
  color: #00ff00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution that I have used many times.

```css
.a {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:#666;
}

.b {
  margin:auto;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  text-align:middle;
  position: relative;
  background-color:#111;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>
  </div>
</div>
```